# Java hosting service provider?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I want to host a Java web application. How to decide which hosting service provider to choose from.
Is there any source of info where from I can get such info. 
Yes most important, being from India which service provider service should I use, from those who say there servers are located in US or they who say their servers are located in India itself.

Thanks in advance from any suggestion/reply to this query.

Comment: This isn't about programming *per se*, so I've voted to move it to webmasters.

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic.  Move to webmasters.

Comment: Move to webmasters. - what does it means and how to do this...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/appengine/) or use a Linux VPS and install [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a good experience with [Java Web Hosting](http://www.cheap-jsp-hosting.com/) for my pscode.org site & 3 others.  They have reliable servers and offer great service/support.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your best option would be to find a cheap [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). I use [123 Systems](http://123systems.net/), they are a budget VPS provider and by no means the best option. I have found the Google App Engine to be a bit limiting from a coding perspective.